# axios ignores baseURL in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

in my app.js

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["token"] =
      process.env.REACT_APP_SITE_TOKEN;
    axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://api.example.com";
  }, []);
```

in my redux action file:

```
export const getCollectionByToken = (token) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log(axios.defaults); //logs https://api.exapmle.com
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/collections/" + token);
    console.log(res);
    dispatch({ type: SET_CURRENT_COLLECTION, payload: res.data });
...
```

but somehow, the requests are going to `http://localhost:3000/collection/<token>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UseEffect is run after the a component is mounted and your redux action is probably compiled before that. The browser console.log is sometimes buggy which print with the wrong sequence.

try:

```
export const getCollectionByToken = (token) => async (dispatch) => {
  axios.defaults.headers.common["token"] =
      process.env.REACT_APP_SITE_TOKEN;
    axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://api.example.com";
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/collections/" + token);
    console.log(res);
    dispatch({ type: SET_CURRENT_COLLECTION, payload: res.data });
    ...
```

or according to the [document](http:////%20Set%20config%20defaults%20when%20creating%20the%20instance%20const%20instance%20=%20axios.create(%7B%20%20%20baseURL:%20'https://api.example.com'%20%7D);%20%20//%20Alter%20defaults%20after%20instance%20has%20been%20created%20instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']%20=%20AUTH_TOKEN;), create an instance somewhere, say a file `axiosConfig.ts`

```
import axios from 'axios'

// Set config defaults when creating the instance
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.example.com'
});

// Alter defaults after instance has been created
axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['token'] = process.env.REACT_APP_SITE_TOKEN;

export default axiosInstance;
```

Then when you want to use axios, import the instance instead of the axios from the library directly:

```
import axiosInstance from './axiosConfig';

export const getCollectionByToken = (token) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axiosInstance.get("/collections/" + token);
    dispatch({ type: SET_CURRENT_COLLECTION, payload: res.data });
    ...
```

Comment: in the file where you import `Axios`, not in `useEffect`

Comment: @MeilechWieder  check my update :)

Comment: @MeilechWieder You don't have to, you can create an instance some where in your project, let's say in app.ts (remember outside, but not anywhere in the app component, or any component), and when you want to use `axios`, you import the instance you created (e.g. `import 'axiosInstances' from 'app.ts'`) instead of `import 'axios' from 'axios'` directly

Comment: @MeilechWieder made an update to the answer about that ^

Answer (score 0):

you can add interceptors, also there is a es6 class wrapper for axios.

```sh
$ npm install @eneto/axios-es6-class
```

you need to create your own api class that will extends from `Api`.

assume we are creating a `class UsersApi`

```js
import { Api } from '@eneto/axios-es6-class';

// process.env.API_BASE_URL = localhost:3001

export class UserApi extends Api {
    public constructor (config) {
        super(config);

        // this middleware is been called right before the http request is made.
        this.interceptors.request.use(param => {
            const {API_BASE_URL} = process.env;
          return {
              ...param,
              baseUrl: API_BASE_URL,
              defaults: {
                  headers: {...param.defaults.headers}
              }
          }
        });

        // this middleware is been called right before the response is get it by the method that triggers the request
        this.interceptors.response.use(param => {
          return {  ...param}
        });

        this.userLogin = this.userLogin.bind(this);
        this.userRegister = this.userRegister.bind(this);
    }

    public userLogin (credentials) {
        return this.post("/login", credentials)
            .then(this.success);
    }

    public userRegister (user) {
        return this.post("/register", user)
            .then(this.success)
            .catch((error) => {
                throw error;
            });
    }


}
```